# Exclude empty Hateoas "links" in the spring boot restapi response

Tags: json, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I have a sample response class that extends RepresentationModel. In some scenarios I don't add any hateoas links in the response. In that case, I'm getting an empty links field in the json response

> "links": []

I tried adding "JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY" to the response class, but since the links field is final in RepresentationModel, it's still bringing empty links field in the response.

How can I avoid this empty links field in the response ?

Comment: The enpty links array should has no harm if the client (consumer) just ignore it. One of the beauty of HATEOAS is links.

Comment: So there is no other option than just accepting the empty links field in the response ?

Comment: I see your JSON property name is "links" instead of "_links". What media type do you use? `application/json` or `application/hal+json`? I look at [`RepresentationModelMixin`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/mediatype/hal/RepresentationModelMixin.java), annotation `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)` is already there. Sharing a runnable Spring Boot demo application in Github to show all configuration is recommanded.

Comment: I'm using `application/json` media type. The reason for my response having `links` is I'm using RepresentationModel - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/RepresentationModel.java

Answer (score 2):

Firstly make sure you have a good reason to use links with media type `application/json` rather than [media type built for hypermedia](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#mediatypes) such as HAL (`application/hal+json`).

Though `RepresentationModel` has a field of `List<Link>`, the getter returns a `Links` instead of `List<Link>`. Jackson treats it as simple type (where a `JsonSerializer` is used) instead of a collection type (where a `CollectionSerializer` is used), so `JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY` doesn't work as you expect.

```java
public class RepresentationModel<T extends RepresentationModel<? extends T>> {

    private final List<Link> links;

    @JsonProperty("links")
    public Links getLinks() {
        return Links.of(links);
    }
}

public class Links implements Iterable<Link> { }

public abstract class JsonSerializer<T> {
    public boolean isEmpty(SerializerProvider provider, T value) {
        return (value == null);
    }
}

public class CollectionSerializer {
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty(SerializerProvider prov, Collection<?> value) {
        return value.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

One solution is override the getter `getLinks()` and use a customm filter.

```java
class User extends RepresentationModel<User> {

    // ...

    @JsonProperty("links")
    // if links is an empty JSON array, exclude it
    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = EmptyLinksFilter.class)
    @Override
    public Links getLinks() {
        return super.getLinks();
    }
}

/* The word "filter" is a bit ambiguous (included? or excluded?).
Here when the equals() of this class return true, the value will be excluded. 
Choose a class name to make yourself comfortable. */
class EmptyLinksFilter{

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Links)) {
            return false;
        }
        Links links = (Links) obj;
        return links.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

The full code is in [Github](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/spring-hateoas-exclude-empty-array).

Second solution may be custom mixin like what Spring HATEOAS already build for HAL. Related code are:

- RepresentationModelMixin
- Jackson2HalModule.HalLinkListSerializer
- Jackson2HalModule
- HalMediaTypeConfiguration

The second solution is much complicated. That's why I recommand media types like HAL, for which Spring HATEOAS already has good configuration.

Comment: +1, It is a good answer there is a lot of good stuffs to test, I am trying to remove that `links` or `_links` only from the `request body` on `swagger`. The point is in the `response body` it is complate fine, but in the `request body` it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer from @yejianfengblue, I have created a custom representation model as below and extended this `CustomRepresentationModel` from response java classes instead of Hateoas `RepresentationModel`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.springframework.hateoas.Links;
import org.springframework.hateoas.RepresentationModel;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;

public class CustomRepresentationModel<T extends CustomRepresentationModel<? extends T>> extends
    RepresentationModel<T> {

  @JsonProperty("_links")
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = NonEmptyLinksFilter.class)
  @NonNull
  @Override
  public Links getLinks() {
    return super.getLinks();
  }

  static class NonEmptyLinksFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (!(obj instanceof Links)) {
        return false;
      }
      Links links = (Links) obj;
      return links.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return super.hashCode();
    }
  }

}
```